# Do Ubuntu and its derivatives have wider support than other Linux distros?

Tags: ubuntu, compatibility, linux-distributions

Do Ubuntu and Ubuntu derivatives have wider support (concerning programs and graphics drivers) than other Linux distributions generally speaking?

Probably Ubuntu and its derivatives are the most widely used Linux desktop distros and that's why it seems to be that many developers focus on these distros. To give an example, [Steam officially supports only Ubuntu](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1504-QHXN-8366&l=german).

So could one say that therefore most software is more likely to run on Ubuntu or its derivatives than on other Linux distros? And will all software that works on Ubuntu also work on other Linux distros?

Answer (score 2):

A [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution), is nothing more than a layer of software and programs on top of the Linux [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)).  Generally speaking, Linux software will run on *any* Linux distribution.

Ubuntu, at the time of this post, has been the most popular Linux desktop distribution.  However, there are literally hundreds of Linux distributions.  A company like Valve, simply cannot support such a wide range of distributions.  Especially, since Linux makes up less than 1% of its sales.  They have to focus on what is most likely to be the distribution of most of its customers.

As for who has better support, that is very subjective.

Comment: "They have to focus on what is most likely to be the distribution of most of its customers." This gives the impression that they would have more effort if they would support more distributions? Why (System dependencies? ; "Linux software will run on any Linux distribution. ")?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Desktop derives its popularity in the Linux ecosystem from two main reasons.

1. Ubuntu has a larger repository of software packages than most other Linux distributions, eliminating the need to drag software in to the filesystem from less trusted sources. Software that can be quickly and easily installed from the default Ubuntu repositories is not always so effortlessly available in other Linux distributions.
2. Ubuntu's motto is "Linux for human beings". Ubuntu provides a friendly and easy to use user experience to ordinary computer users.